# How to allow user to download entire folder, directory, or at least multiple images? (Flask)

Tags: html, forms, flask, download

I am trying to figure out **how to allow user to download a folder that contains multiple images** when the user presses download button. For now, I can only use send_file code to allow user to download a single image. Is there any possible way to do this?

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
   path = "where my image is"
   return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)
```

This is my current code and I want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to archive the directory and then send it.

A list of all files in the folder is created.
These files are then compressed in a zip archive that is written to a stream.
The stream is then transmitted via send_file.

```
from flask import send_file
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO
import os, glob

@app.route('/download', methods=['GET'])
def download():
    path = # target directory
    root = os.path.dirname(path)
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*'))
    stream = BytesIO()
    with ZipFile(stream, 'w') as zf:
        for f in files:
            zf.write(f, os.path.relpath(f, root))
    stream.seek(0)
    return send_file(
        stream,
        as_attachment=True,
        attachment_filename='archive.zip',
        mimetype='application/zip'
    )
```